# Convert three lines of text to two

Tags: python

I have the following text spread over three lines:

```
Aguardo o Sr. Miller,
responsável
pela Segurança da Estação
```

Is there a function or python module that could convert this into 2 (or 4) lines in the most 'normal' way, i.e., their line lengths are as close to equal as possible? For example:

```
format_lines(text=s, lines=2)
Aguardo o Sr. Miller, responsável
pela Segurança da Estação
```

Comment: Please define "most normal way". What is your criterion? Having line lengths as close to equal as possible?

Comment: @Amadan -- yes, the length as close to equal as possible.

Comment: ...or does the line-merging criterion need to parse natural language, understand or spot short or subsidiary phrases and know they can be merged?

Comment: @smci no merging would be necessary here.

Comment: David542, your own example is asking us to merge lines 0 and 1!

Comment: @smci sorry, I meant words don't need to be merged, in the case of a hyphenated word. Grammar or readability doesn't matter. I'm merely interested in the text-lengths being as similar as possible.

Comment: once you don't care too much about how readable it is this should work for python3 http://pastebin.com/Z9Qiq6XL